# WordPress にて 特定のプラグインをテーマから無効化することは可能ですか？

Tags: wordpress

現在スマホから閲覧した場合はスマホ用テーマ、
PCから閲覧した場合はPC用テーマ表示しております。
スマホ用テーマのみ、無効化したいプラグインがあります。
function.phpなどに記載して無効化したいのですが、こういったことは可能でしょうか？